# How does addEventListener uniquely identify the functions passed to it?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Say I have some code like this:

```js
let myFunc = () => {
    console.log("hello");
}
 
document.addEventListener("click", myFunc);
document.addEventListener("click", myFunc);
document.addEventListener("click", myFunc);
document.addEventListener("click", myFunc);
```

Why does clicking the document only console log once? I don't mind this behavior, but I'm just curious how it is implemented.

For example, if you did something like this:

```
let events = {};

function addEventListener(key, callback) {
  if (!key) { return; }

  if (!events.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    events[key] = {};
  }

  events[key][callback] = callback;
}
```

Then you're using a function as a key, but aren't only strings valid for keys? How does JavaScript uniquely identify the functions so that it knows not to add the same one multiple times?

Answer (score 1):

A given event listener with a particular configuration can only be added to an element *once* - if you add it multiple times, as you can see, it will be as if only a single listener was added. This is described in the specification [here](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#add-an-event-listener):

> 3. If eventTarget’s event listener list does not contain an event listener whose type is listener’s type, callback is listener’s callback, and capture is listener’s capture, then append listener to eventTarget’s event listener list.

To expand on that, for a listener to be considered such a duplicate:

> whose type is listener’s type

refers to the event name, eg `'click'`

> callback is listener’s callback

which must be the same function reference (`===` to a prior listener added)

> capture is listener’s capture

refers to whether the listener listens in the capturing phase or the bubbling phase. (This is set by a third boolean parameter to `addEventListener`, which defaults to `true` - bubbling, or with `{ capture: boolean }` as the third argument)

If all of the above are the same as that of a listener added previously, then the new listener will be considered a duplicate, and will not be added again.

---

An easy way to add such a listener multiple times, if you wanted, would be to make an inline callback that calls your listener:

```js
let myFunc = () => {
    console.log("hello");
}
 
document.addEventListener("click", () => myFunc());
document.addEventListener("click", () => myFunc());
document.addEventListener("click", () => myFunc());
document.addEventListener("click", () => myFunc());
```

```html
click me
```

The above will work because the callbacks passed to `addEventListener` are not equal: `() => myFunc()` is not `===` to `() => myFunc()`.

Comment: Yes, I'm curious how this is implemented though. How does Javascript know that the event listener callback has already been added? To clarify, I don't want to have function run 4 times, I only want to know how they uniquely identify the functions.

Comment: See the quote from the specification in the answer. *If eventTarget’s event listener list does not contain an event listener whose type is listener’s type, callback is listener’s callback, and capture is listener’s capture, then append listener to eventTarget’s event listener list.* If the same listener was added before, then the event listener list *will* have such an identical item, so a new listener won't be added.

Comment: @RyanPeschel Functions are objects. You can compare them with `===`. The browser does this internally in `addEventListener`

Comment: So they just have an array of functions and just iterate through the existing ones when you add a new one to make sure it's not already added? Is there any way to avoid the O(n) of this? I was hoping to avoid iterating through the existing list which is why I was originally thinking about using objects.

Comment: @RyanPeschel `Map` exists as well, but the W3C specification for `addEventListener` existed long before `Map` was part of ECMAScript.

Comment: @RyanPeschel The specification doesn't describe the complexity, but I wouldn't be at all surprised if it was `O(1)`. It could well be implemented like a Set - an unordered collection of listeners which can be looked up in `O(1)` time.

Comment: But is this possible to do in user-code (store functions as keys in objects with O(1) retrieval)? Like, if I wanted to implement the same thing. I'd have to use the function pointers as keys or something, but I don't know how to get that. If I try to just use the function as a key then it doesn't work.

Comment: @RyanPeschel Like I said, it could well be implemented like a Set. `const set = new Set(); set.add(fn); console.log(set.has(fn))` will log `true`, and will run in `O(1)` time regardless of the number of items in the Set

Comment: Ah okay so if you use a Set then it works? That's good to know, thanks.,

Answer (score 0):

The implementation could be something conceptually like this (I'm ignoring the details of the specification not relevant to the question):

```
function addEventListener(type, listener, useCapture = false) {
    let typeListeners = this.eventListeners[type];
    if (!typeListeners) {
        this.eventListeners[type] = [{function: listener, useCapture: useCapture}];
    } else {
        let found = typeListeners.find(l => l.function === listener && l.useCapture == useCapture);
        if (!found) {
            typeListeners.push({function: listener, useCapture: useCapture});
        }
    }
}
```

It searches the list of listeners for the event type, for an existing match to the function and `useCapture` parameters. If it's not already there, it adds it.

Comment: Right, this uses an array. Is it possible to do with objects so you can have O(1) retrieval?

Comment: It might be, but why bother? It's unusual to have multiple listeners for the same event on an element, and very rare to have so many that linear search would be a performance problem.

Comment: I'd expect that 90% of the time the hashing algorithm would be more expensive than linear.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. I'm probably going to use linear because it's likely to be faster and it's also simpler. I was just wondering if it was possible to uniquely identify functions in an object. Looks like I would need to use a Map or Set. Good to know, thanks!

Comment: @RyanPeschel It also needs to check the `useCapture` flag.